# Smooth and decaying matrix coefficients

Tags: rt.representation-theory, nuclear-spaces, tempered-distributions

I want to talk about the matrix coefficients
$$ f(g) = \langle \pi(g) v, \alpha^* \rangle.$$

Here $(\pi, V_\pi)$ is a representation of a Lie group $G$, with $V_\pi$ being a topological vector space and $v \in V_\pi$ is some special vector such as a Schwarz function. The dual vector $\alpha^*$ may simply be another $L^2$ function and $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ may be considered as the simple Hilbert space inner product but I want to rather consider more general *tempered distributions* (Dirac delta or integration for example).

What is the framework that I should be thinking this in? What generality allows me to say that $f$ is a smooth function? Or that it decays quickly enough to be square integrable (or just $L^p$) etc?

The concept of smooth vectors $v \in V_\pi^\infty$ come to mind. But the definition of such a vector **that I know** is when the map $g \mapsto \langle \pi(g)v, w\rangle $ is a smooth function from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}$ for any $w$ in the Hilbert space $V_\pi$. Would that imply $f$ defined above is smooth as well for not-necessarily-continuous linear functionals $\alpha^*$?

Or should I start with an $\alpha^*$ and consider the vectors $v$ that are **"smooth with respect to the linear functional $\alpha^*$''**, or define something in that vein?

Comment: Perhaps you are interested in defining all the relevant notions only with respect to the representation data $(G, V_\pi, \pi)$. In that case I don't know the answer. But maybe it would be enough for you to compare with the standard notions of Schwartz functions on groups and homogeneous spaces (and dually tempered distributions on them). In that case, have a look at [this article](https://core.ac.uk/display/82715485) by van den Ban.